# Update StringVar() with new entry and keeping previous one

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm working on a HANGMAN Game, and I'm stuck on where Label updates with Entry.get() by StringVar().
Everything works correctly,except this one line. It is still WIP project so there is not much to do.
So, basically i want to get something like c__ and after entry i get c_r but it works like (c__ , __r) that

here is the def that updates StringVar()

```
def get_word(hide_randomize, randomize,random_word):
    if user_get in randomize:
        word_as_list = list(hide_randomize)
        indices = [i for i, letter in enumerate(randomize) if letter == user_get]
        for index in indices:
            word_as_list[index] = user_get
        hide_randomize = "".join(word_as_list)
        random_word.set(hide_randomize)
```

and here is full code

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

words_list = ['auto', 'miasto', 'rower']


def main_window():
    global letter_entry
    global user_input
    global guessed
    guessed = False
    #tries = 5
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('HANGMAN')
    random_word = tk.StringVar()
    random_word.set(hide_randomize)
    letter_entry = tk.Entry(root)
    letter_entry.place(x=135, y=50)
    letter_label = tk.Label(root, text='Enter your letter:', bg='black', fg='white')
    letter_label.place(x=40, y=50)
    name_label = tk.Label(root, text='HANGMAN', font=32, fg='white', relief="raised", bg='black')
    name_label.place(x=150, y=10)
    user_input = tk.Label(root, bg='white')
    user_input.place(x=200, y=200)
    word_label = tk.Label(root, bg='white', text='Your word is:')
    word_label.place(x=73, y=250)
    random_words = tk.Label(root, bg='white', textvariable=random_word)
    random_words.place(x=150, y=250)
    enter_button = tk.Button(root, text='INSERT', font=24,
                             command=lambda:
                             [get_entry(letter_entry, user_input),
                             get_word(hide_randomize, randomize,random_word)])
    enter_button.place(x=160, y=80)
    root.geometry('400x450')
    root.configure(bg='black')
    root.mainloop()


def get_entry(letter_entry, user_input):
    global user_get
    user_get = letter_entry.get()
    user_input['text'] = user_get
    return user_get


def get_word(hide_randomize, randomize,random_word):
        if user_get in randomize:
            word_as_list = list(hide_randomize)
            indices = [i for i, letter in enumerate(randomize) if letter == user_get]
            for index in indices:
                word_as_list[index] = user_get
            hide_randomize = "".join(word_as_list)
            random_word.set(hide_randomize)


def random_words(words_list):
    global hide_randomize
    global randomize
    randomize = random.choice(words_list)
    hide_randomize = "_" * len(randomize)
    print(randomize)
    print(hide_randomize)
    return hide_randomize

random_words(words_list)
main_window()
```

***EDIT:***

figure it out by myself, just needed to make a list of user_get and instead of random.word.set(hide_randomize) changed it to random.word.set("".join(word_as_list))

Comment: Get rid of `command=lambda:...`it's complicating things. You can't return any value from a callback. Where did you think is the return value of `[get_entry(...` assigned to?

Comment: is it? without lambda it won't work ;/. Well, to variable?

Comment: ***without lambda it won't work***: With `lambda` it won't work as well. Replace with `command=<your callback>`. Within your callback, do what you need to do. ***Well, to variable?***: Which variable, where is it defined?

Comment: ye i did return value to nothing so i deleted it, and w/o lambda it didn't work, with lambda it does :)

Comment: ***with lambda it does***: So, is your issue solved? Consider to close or delete this question